# Question related to current View

Tags: android

Is there any way by which we can get the current view by specifying the position of the view?

I have the view position with me and I need to get View. Is there any way?

Comment: Could you elaborate please? What exactly do you want to learn, the device's orientation?

Comment: i have x and y position with me and i need to know which view is present in that x and y position.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know what root `View` you should start with, you can just walk down the hierarchy using a depth-first search. When going up or down in level, offset your coordinates by results of `getLeft` and `getTop` methods, which return the coordinates of specific `View` relative to its level.